# Vertical aligning :after element within parent container (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align text to the center of it's parent container, but it is aligning a little farther down than center.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrvo6txq/1/

CSS:

```
.caret-right {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.caret-right:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: .15s;
    -webkit-transition: .15s;
    -moz-transition: .15s;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f105"; /* fa-angle-right */
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.caret-right:hover:after {
    right: 4%;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="caret-right" href="#" title="Get Started">

  <div class="box">

    <p class="align-center">Get started now with <span class="color-theme-a">5 free lessons</span>.</p>

    <p class="align-center">No credit card needed</p>

  </div>

</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `transform: translateY(-50%);` to your `.caret-right:after` rule:

```
.caret-right:after {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This correctly offsets your element 50% of its height to vertically center your caret:

```css
.caret-right {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.caret-right:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: .15s;
  -webkit-transition: .15s;
  -moz-transition: .15s;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  /* fa-angle-right */
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.caret-right:hover:after {
  right: 4%;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="caret-right" href="#" title="Get Started">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="align-center">Get started now with <span class="color-theme-a">5 free lessons</span>.</p>
    <p class="align-center">No credit card needed</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To perfectly vertically center the `.caret-right:after`, leave the 50% `top` value and add the following:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the CSS3 `transform` property is to assign a specific value for the line-height of `.caret-right` and then use a negative top margin to one-half of the line-height.

Personally, I prefer the `transform: translateY(-50%)` rule but it is good to know how to do it with an alternative approach.

```css
.caret-right {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.caret-right:after {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .15s;
  -webkit-transition: .15s;
  -moz-transition: .15s;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  /* fa-angle-right */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;

}

.caret-right:hover:after {
  right: 4%;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="caret-right" href="#" title="Get Started">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="align-center">Get started now with <span class="color-theme-a">5 free lessons</span>.</p>
    <p class="align-center">No credit card needed</p>
  </div>
</a>
```